# My android project no longer starts in emulator

Tags: android

My Android project no longer starts in the emulator. On the console, it says loading apk and installing, but it never says Starting Activty. I also put a breakpoint on the first line of code, but it never gets there.
Ted

Comment: Look at logcat to see what is happening.

Comment: I'm guessing you won't get any useful help without posting your logcat trace, or some offending code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like its facing some problem while installing. Mostly when you face a problem with installations it might have something to do with signing of the APK. There is a chance that, there is a copy already installed on your emulator with different signature. In that case android will not allow you to override it with new one.

So suggestions:
1. Check if there is an APK. Just go through list of applications
2. If there is one, uninstall it by 'adb uninstall '
3. Try again

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your manifest file is not correct? A lot of problems can be traced to that file. Also, you should clean your project as this can also solve a lot of strange problems.

Without any code or examples I can't say any better

Comment: Hi,Thank you for the comment, I did check the menfest file, seemed ok.

Comment: 10 years later and I just ran into this.  I tried everything listed here.  Logcat has no helpful information:

Comment: I would post the logcat but it's too long for a comment

Comment: The emulator shows the app icon but clicking it: App isn't installed.  This is a debug instance with no signature and has been working fine for quite a while.

Comment: Debug output:
09/02 12:01:55: Launching 'Metals' on Nexus 5X API 28 x86.
App restart successful without requiring a re-install.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.metals/com.metals.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -D
Waiting for application to come online: com.metals | com.metals.test
.
.
Waiting for application to come online: com.metals | com.metals.test
Could not connect to remote process. Aborting debug session.

Comment: This is related to upgrading gradle as I updated the application that was working and now the same thing happens to it.